# slim template iniline ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I''m trying to include some ruby code in slim template, this is the code I want to put in slim:

```
      - nav_links_group = nil
      - if if_page_var('visible', :main_menu, :solutions)
      -   nav_links_group = @nav_links["solutions"]
      - elsif if_page_var('visible', :main_menu, :resources)
      -   nav_links_group = @nav_links["resources"]
      - elsif if_page_var('visible', :main_menu, :people)
      -   nav_links_group = @nav_links["people"]
      -end

      - if nav_links_group
      - current_index = nav_links_group.map{|e| e[0]}.index(request.original_url)
        - if current_index == 0
          span = sub_menu_link "#{nav_links_group[current_index + 1][0]}", "#{nav_links_group[current_index + 1][1]}"
        - elsif current_index + 1 == nav_links_group.count
          span = sub_menu_link "#{nav_links_group[current_index - 1][0]}", "#{nav_links_group[current_index - 1][1]}"
        - elsif current_index > 0 && current_index + 1 != nav_links_group.count
          span = sub_menu_link "#{nav_links_group[current_index - 1][0]}", "#{nav_links_group[current_index - 1][1]}"
          span = sub_menu_link "#{nav_links_group[current_index + 1][0]}", "#{nav_links_group[current_index + 1][1]}"
        - end
      - end
```

I got the error:
syntax error, unexpected keyword_elsif

any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot have `- end` in Slim

Comment: I have the same error without - end

Comment: Maybe the error is in this method `if_page_var`, what does it look like?

Comment: no, the if_page_var is ok, seems like problem is in if/elsif

Comment: Is there no line number with the error?

Answer (score 8):

If you need to do multiline ruby in slim and you aren't adding elements, you can use `ruby:` and then put the code indented under it.

For your other code, simply remove the `end` keywords

```
ruby:
  nav_links_group = nil
  if if_page_var('visible', :main_menu, :solutions)
    nav_links_group = @nav_links["solutions"]
  elsif if_page_var('visible', :main_menu, :resources)
    nav_links_group = @nav_links["resources"]
  elsif if_page_var('visible', :main_menu, :people)
    nav_links_group = @nav_links["people"]
  end

- if nav_links_group
  - current_index = nav_links_group.map{|e| e[0]}.index(request.original_url)
  - if current_index == 0
    span= sub_menu_link "#{nav_links_group[current_index + 1][0]}", "#{nav_links_group[current_index + 1][1]}"
  - elsif current_index + 1 == nav_links_group.count
    span= sub_menu_link "#{nav_links_group[current_index - 1][0]}", "#{nav_links_group[current_index - 1][1]}"
  - elsif current_index > 0 && current_index + 1 != nav_links_group.count
    span= sub_menu_link "#{nav_links_group[current_index - 1][0]}", "#{nav_links_group[current_index - 1][1]}"
    span= sub_menu_link "#{nav_links_group[current_index + 1][0]}", "#{nav_links_group[current_index + 1][1]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

reviewing your code, i can say that your issue was :

- slim doesn't use `- end`
- your indentations are messed
- don't use space between tag and '=' (use `span= sub_menu_link`, not `span = sub_menu_link`)

here some example

```
- nav_links_group = nil
- if if_page_var('visible', :main_menu, :solutions)
  - nav_links_group = @nav_links["solutions"]
- elsif if_page_var('visible', :main_menu, :resources)
  - nav_links_group = @nav_links["resources"]
- elsif if_page_var('visible', :main_menu, :people)
  - nav_links_group = @nav_links["people"]

- if nav_links_group
  - current_index = nav_links_group.map{|e| e[0]}.index(request.original_url)
  - if current_index == 0
    span= sub_menu_link "#{nav_links_group[current_index + 1][0]}", "#{nav_links_group[current_index + 1][1]}"
  - elsif current_index + 1 == nav_links_group.count
    span= sub_menu_link "#{nav_links_group[current_index - 1][0]}", "#{nav_links_group[current_index - 1][1]}"
  - elsif current_index > 0 && current_index + 1 != nav_links_group.count
    span= sub_menu_link "#{nav_links_group[current_index - 1][0]}", "#{nav_links_group[current_index - 1][1]}"
    span= sub_menu_link "#{nav_links_group[current_index + 1][0]}", "#{nav_links_group[current_index + 1][1]}"
```